# Add Table to the predefined image template and download it as an image file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a sale bill image with a predefined template, it contains a header with logo and  footer with some other content. I would give the details in a form then it would generate an image with the bill details inside the predefined template How to do this with react js or js

Comment: OK, so, what is your question? You seem to be describing something that you're creating, so would have quite a bit of code already. Can you show what you have so far

Comment: how can i achieve this with react

Comment: well, you'll need to show the code you've written so far - otherwise we have no idea about your data structures etc